# RegEx match specific pattern in a text "[d-n]"

Tags: c#, regex

What would be a regex for matching "[d-n]", where n is any number?

i.e.
Test_4_[d-123] - returns ideally only 123

or, if I can return [d-123] I could make some string formatting.

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't here to do your work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you. Here, a quick search on how to match digits in a RegEx would be enough.

Comment: Post your attempts, please.

Comment: I've tried [d\-[\d\]] and [\d] but both of them match any number not only inside [d-]

Comment: You may use something like [`(?<=\[d-)\d+]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5bd-%29%5cd%2b&i=Test_4_%5bd-123%5d) which returns `123`

Comment: `"\[d\-(?<number>[0-9]+)\]"`

Comment: `\[d-(\d+)\]` and get the first group.

Comment: `^\w+\[d-(\d+)\]$` matches `Test_4_[d-123]` and puts `123` into group 1.

Comment: Please, provide *examples* both positive and negative ones

Comment: I'll leave this question and accept an answer to this question since I've learned from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?<=\[d-)\d+(?=\])` will return `123` from `Test_4_[d-123]`.

Comment: I like this solution. No need for retrieving match groups as in my solution. +1

Comment: Thanks, when I put it into https://regex101.com/ gives me nice explanation why

Answer (score 0):

You give very little information as to how you want stuff matched.

A very simple solution could be:
`\[d-(\d+)\]`

From left to right:

- `\[` will match the literal character [
- `d-` will match just d-
- `(\d+)` will match any digit one or more times. It is in parenthesis, which makes it a capture/match group. This should mean that if you are using a regex tool/library, you should be able to retrieve the "first match group" and you should retrieve just 123.
- `\]` will match the literal character ]

I can only suggest using a website like https://regex101.com/ which can help in creating regular expressions.